# Change cite color to blue in the Legrand Orange Book template

Tags: hyperref, color, templates

In the code below, that was derived from the Legrand Orange Book template, I wanted to be able to change the cite color.  However, when I activated the `colorlinks=true`, the table of contents (TOC) got affected.  How to maintain the TOC, while being able to change the `cite` color.

I would like to maintain this format and coloring for the TOC:

[image]

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\BoxColor{ocre!60}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{0cm}

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{\color{ocre}}
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part};
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,
            %colorlinks=true,
            %linkcolor = ocre,
            backref=true,
            pagebackref=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            pdftitle={Title},
            pdfauthor={Author}}

\usepackage[sorting=none,
            sortcites=true,
            autopunct=true,
            babel=hyphen,
            hyperref=true,
            abbreviate=false,
            backref=true,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{fancy}

\part{Part One}

\chapter{Text Chapter}

\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}

\lipsum[1-2]~\cite{Knu86}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}
\lipsum[1-2]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *the toc gets affected*? Have you tried `linkcolor=black`? Is this in any way related to the template?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I have added an image for the original format for the TOC that I would like to  maintain (that is template specific).

Comment: I hate templates. `linkcolor = .,`

Comment: @Joe: Your obsession to this Orange book stuff is scary ;-)

Comment: Can we mark [Change cite color with hidelinks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278117) as a duplicate of this question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer...I know, I know...I just like it...ok, I am obsessed with it.  I just really like the layout!  Thanks.

Comment: Did the proposed solution work?

Comment: No, I could not get it to work without affecting the TOC.

Comment: @Joe I could, worked perfectly.

Comment: @Johannes_B, can you post a little snippet of what you did?

Comment: I *just* replaced the name of the color (black or ocre or whatever) with a `.` (dot), which holds information of the *current8 color.

Comment: @Johannes_B, Thank you very much Sir.  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `linkcolor = .` uses the same color that the surrounding text is using.

Comment: @Rico Well, apart from the obvious typo, it does answer the question quite well. And since i did not find a suitable dupe, i wrote a CW answer.

Comment: Wrong button, my bad